# Angular foreach orderby

Tags: angularjs

In `ng-repeat` there is an option to order the data by using `trackby` or `orderby`. To get the data by the needed data order like that I need to order the data using `angular.foreach`. Is there any option to order the looping data?

Comment: foreach is use to iterate over object. so my question is why you need orderby in forEach ?

Comment: i need to iterate the data with ordered format that's why i asked this @nitz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OrderBy is a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) in Angularjs, so you can use its JS form

```
$filter('orderBy')(collection, expression, reverse, comparator)
```

In foreach:

```
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', 'orderByFilter', function($scope, orderByFilter) {
    angular.forEach(orderByFilter(list, propertyName, reverse), function(value, key) {
    // Your code here
    });
}]);
```